# Как осуществляется перетаскивание в слайдерах

Tags: javascript

Собсно задача: хотят вот такой слайдер https://www.redbull.com/ru-ru/energydrink/red-bull-energy-drink-sostav
Как написать такое я представляю. Но не очень понимаю как осуществляется перетаскивание элементов пальцем на сенсорных экранах. Я конечно попробовал посмотреть, но там все минимизировано... Может кто-нибудь подсказать?

Comment: Можно написать велосипед, а можно воспользоваться решением из примера https://flickity.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Если посмотреть, как перетаскивается в примере в адаптивном режиме, там сдвигаются именно элементы, причем довольно хитро. слайдер по ссылке двигает весь контейнер. По крайней мере до меня не доходит как сделать подобное на основе известных мне слайдеров